# Is there any azure powershell command to know total CPU cores comes with your azure subscription?

Tags: azure, cpu

I want to know if there is any powershell command that will tell you total number of CPU cores assigned to your  azure subscription . I read here http://cloudpower.no/?p=1002 with 3-month free trial subscription it is going to be 20 CPU cores and the number of CPU cores increases if you move to paid account. I want to get these values programmatically via azure commands. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for this:

Get-AzureSubscription -ExtendedDetails

Best regards,

Patriek van Dorp
@pvandorp
http://onwindowsazure.com

Comment: +1 Thanks,`MaxCoreCount`-`CurrentCoreCount` = the core count left.It is helpful.